# Inserting text into database

Tags: php, html

Can someone try to figure out why isnt this form entering inout data into my DB.

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row" style="margin-top:200px;">

            <form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="upload.php" METHOD=POST>

                Upload this file: 
                <input NAME="file_up" TYPE="file">
                <input type="text" name="tag1" placeholder="Enter Tag 1"  /><br/>
                <input type="text" name="tag2" placeholder="Enter Tag 2"  /><br/>
                <input type="text" name="tag3" placeholder="Enter Tag 3"  /><br/>
                <input type="text" name="tag4" placeholder="Enter Tag 4"  /><br/>
                <input type="text" name="tag5" placeholder="Enter Tag 5"  /><br/>
                <input type="text" name="tag6" placeholder="Enter Tag6"  /><br/>

                <input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File">
            </form>

        </div>
</div>

    <!-- /.container -->
<?php
    $tag1 = $_POST['tag1'];
    $tag2 = $_POST['tag2'];
    $tag3 = $_POST['tag3'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tag (`tag1`, `tag2`, `tag3`) VALUES ('$tag1', '$tag2', '$tag3')"; 
        $sql_insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }


    ?>
```

So im trying to insert image tags for search purpose.but this form doesnt do anything.$conn i set up corectly bcouse it worked with my other queries. i cant figure out what did i do wrong. . .

Comment: What is the name of the file you have posted?

Comment: This is a good example as to why you should not use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` (there are others as well). I suggest you use  `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {`

Comment: @chris Its a cut from upload file.Script purpose is to upload image,and tags with it. JimL It didnt change anything,error log is also empty

Answer (score -1):

Problem was in :

```
<input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File">
```

I forgot to add `name="submit"`

So

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

didn't work.

Like that :

```
<input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File" name="send">


if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
```